# How do change Spine animations in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, spine

I have a conditional if then statement running where I want the animations to change if a certain condition is met.  For some reason when it starts, the correct animation plays, but when it is changed the animation doesn't change.  The code is running in `LateUpdate()`.  I made a hack to test the changing of the animations and it won't work either.

Everything I have read says to use `SetAnimation` and it will over ride the previous animation, but this doesn't seem to be working.  Here is the code to hack that result I want.

```
rightCrowdMemberAnimation.state.SetAnimation (0, "idle_07", true);

if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {

rightCrowdMemberAnimation.state.SetAnimation (0, "yay_07", true);

}
```

Thanks for the help.

What is weird is that the in the inspector it says that the animation has changed, but visually it hasn't changed.

Note: This is what i was trying to accomplish.  It appears that while I was in `LateUpdate`it was resetting back to the idle when I clicked A.  I am still not sure why it won't change the animation under what is below.  I thought the A button trick was similar in execution, but I guess I was wrong.

```
void Start(){
    Assume I did a random roll of color {red,blue,yellow}
}
```

The real issue is

```
void LateUpdate(){
     if (color = red) {
         rightCrowdMemberAnimation.state.SetAnimation (0, "idle_07", true);
     } else if (color = blue) {
         rightCrowdMemberAnimation.state.SetAnimation (0, "idle_08", true);
     } else if (color = yellow){
         rightCrowdMemberAnimation.state.SetAnimation (0, "idle_09", true);
     }
}
```

In the inspector the animation I want to show up is there. Just the animation that I am calling isn't showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to change property `AnimationName` on `SkeletonAnimation` script. Here is sample:

```
private SkeletonAnimation skeletonAnimation;

void Awake()
{
    skeletonAnimation = GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation>();
}

void LateUpdate(){
     if (color = red) {
         skeletonAnimation.AnimationName = "idle_07";
     } else if (color = blue) {
         skeletonAnimation.AnimationName = "idle_08";
     } else if (color = yellow){
         skeletonAnimation.AnimationName = "idle_09";
     }
}
```